# How to select all emails from mysql table and assign it to $to of mail function in php?

Tags: php, mysql, email

Actually i want to email to all users so, small problem regarding selection of all emails from MySQL's table in PHP. how can i use select query to select all emails from table and assign them to $to with separating each email with comma. I have tried various things. This doesn't work. I have a table "users" with fields like id,name,email,mobile,address,password.

Any help would be appreciated !

**Code :**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $comments = $_POST['comments'];
  $to = "$allemail";

  $headers = "From:$name<$email>";
  $message = "Name: $name\n\n Email: $email \n\n Subject : $subject \n\n Message : $comments";
  if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "Email Send";
  } else {
    echo "Error : Please Try Again !";
  }
}

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "testdb";


 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "select group_concat(email separator ',') as email FROM users";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
 {

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    $allemail =$row["email"];
  }
 } 
 else {
 echo "0 results";
 }
 $conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Mail Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post" >
      <p>Name :<br>
      <input type="text" name="name" id=""></p>
      <p>Email :<br>
      <input type="text" name="email" id=""></p>
      <p>Subject :<br>
      <input type="text" name="subject" id=""></p>
      <p>Comments :<br>
      <textarea name="comments" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to see any select query?

Comment: Where is your query and for that matter your connection to the DB?

Comment: you can concatenate emails with the ',' symbol inside the string of the $to variable, but where is the query?

Comment: "*..And I haven't seen any problems quite like this one on here.*" ~ Seriously?

Comment: you mis lot of things

Comment: Please have a look I update the code

Comment: $sql = "SELECT group_concat(email separator ',') FROM users"; that's it see my answer too

Comment: @Kool-Mind Ok i just push code to server after 15 min i can test that it will working or not

Comment: how many emails are there? if it's in great number den echo and check does it's comma separated?

Comment: @Kool-Mind Too much mails i don't understand what you say ?

Comment: just echo the result of query by using limit 10 in query and see does the output is comma separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use group_concat for it

```
$query = 'select group_concat(email separator ',') as email FROM users';
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
     $to = $row;
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

$to will be comma separated pass it to mail function

Comment: If i use select group_concat(email separator ',') FROM users With my code then "Notice: Undefined index: email in......" is display may be in $allemail =$row["email"]; email is act as a index etc

Comment: use select group_concat(email separator ',')  as email FROM users

Comment: Ok, i test  $allemail =$row["email"]; with echo it holds all emails with comma now i push code to server i hope so it may works.

Comment: Got Error : Please Try Again ! the else condition is running. Something i am missing i think !

Comment: echo $result->num_rows; exit; and see what's the count

Comment: When i echo it shows like 1,a@aa.com,A@g.com,An@a.com,dsa@ds,Harry@mail.com etc. can this 1 creates any issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121249/discussion-between-john120-and-kool-mind).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Database Driver to select data from the database and use that as input for your e-mails.

This is not a 'problem' but lack of knowledge to achieve the goal you want.
You can gain the correct amount of knowlegde by following 'Mysql & PHP' tutorials you'll find to be online quite abundant.

1. First read and understand this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp
2. Then try to implement a solution
3. If you have real problems, come back here and post details about the issues encountered.

Success!